# Getting the HTML tags in hpple as well as text?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, parsing, hpple

The code below takes all of the text from a certain div. Is it possible for me to take all the text from the div as well as the html attributes? So it also adds all of the `<p> </p>'s` and `<br> </br>'s` to the string, myString?

```
//trims string from previous page
        NSString *trimmedString = [stringy stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; 

    NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trimmedString]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];    
    NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@class='field-item even']"];
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements lastObject]; //may need to change this number?!
    NSString *mystring = [self getStringForTFHppleElement:element];

    trimmedTextView.text = [trimmedTextView.text stringByAppendingString:mystring];
```

Method here:

```
-(NSString*) getStringForTFHppleElement:(TFHppleElement *)element 
{

NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];

// Iterate recursively through all children
for (TFHppleElement *child in [element children])
    [result appendString:[self getStringForTFHppleElement:child]];

// Hpple creates a <text> node when it parses texts
if ([element.tagName isEqualToString:@"text"])
    [result appendString:element.content];

return result;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *htmlDataString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

This will take all the HTML out to string. You can then parse it in your native code and find div which is your interest what you have did in above example.

You can do it as well with any DOM element in your HTML like:

```
NSString *htmlDataString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.getElemenById('mydiv')"];
```

which is more efficient but requires a bit of javascript skill.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after trying your second method and debugging it the string its returning is @"" ?
NSString *htmlDataString = [newView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('class1')"];

Comment: Well you have to be sure what your javaScript string returns before you put it into action. I use Firefox+firebug combination for testing my javascript things

Comment: Using your second string, should it matter if the div class is nested? Or should it find it anywhere on the page?

Comment: It should find the first that matches, no matter where it is. But you cannot mismatch div id with div class. Those are different things.

Comment: my div class is called field-item even what should the javascript be, as ive tried inserting that into the code I posted above but its not working. Your first piece of code does work though so its not a problem with the web view.